Every time I make wudu I need to pass gas
Salamalaykum Everytime I need to make Wudu I need to fart or when I’m praying also but if I’m not praying or making wudu I don’t need to fart I use to deal with waswas but now that I don’t take long to make wudu a new problem has occurred I don’t know if it’s waswas
